# XML attribute for datepicker selector color

Tags: android, xml, datepicker

This is probably a really simple question, but for some reason I can't find the answer. I have a datepicker in my app, and in the XML file for the activity I want to set the color of the selector circle around the selected date. What attribute should I use to define that?

```
<DatePicker 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/dateNeededPicker"
    android:headerBackground="@color/colorPrefab"> 
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: give us some code so we can try it out. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the "colorAccent" .  By default it takes the app accent color, If not then could you be more specific about your problem.

Comment: What I mean is, what attribute am I defining? For example, to set the id I use android:id. What would I use to set the color of the selector?